Default properties in a context doesn't use the value object to overwrite them
I'm scaffolding a basic NextJS 14 app, I'm going to use some properties globally and I construct a global context called AppContext, with this approach I'll be able to read some general data as user info, global state of the application, etc.
This is the context file that I use:
import React from 'react';

// Define the interface for the context props
export interface AppContextProps {
    isDrawerOpen: boolean;
    setIsDrawerOpen: (value: boolean) => void;
}

// Create the context and assign the default values
export const AppContext = React.createContext<AppContextProps>({
    isDrawerOpen: false,
    setIsDrawerOpen: () => {},
});

// Create a provider component
export const AppContextProvider: React.FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
    const [isDrawerOpen, setIsDrawerOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
//In the value attribute, I'm replacing the defaults with a new object with the variable and the setter of the state
    return (
        <AppContext.Provider
            value={{
                isDrawerOpen,
                setIsDrawerOpen,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );
};
//Export the hook to use the context
export const useAppContext = () => React.useContext(AppContext);


The issue comes when I use the hook:
const { isDrawerOpen, setIsDrawerOpen } = useAppContext();
once I try to set the value of isDrawerOpen using setIsDrawerOpen(!isDrawerOpen) the value of isDrawerOpen is never update.
example of implementation
const GlobalLayout: React.FC<GlobalLayoutProps> = props => {
    const { isDrawerOpen, setIsDrawerOpen } = useAppContext();
    const [drawerWidth, setDrawerWidth] = useState<string>('68px');

    const toggleDrawer = () => {
        setIsDrawerOpen(!isDrawerOpen);
    };
    //This useEffect never triggers because isDrawerOpen never changes
    useEffect(() => {
        if (isDrawerOpen) {
            setDrawerWidth('240px');
        } else {
            setDrawerWidth('68px');
        }
    }, [isDrawerOpen]);

    return (
     <AppContextProvider>
       <Button onClick={toggleDrawer}>Test</Button>.
     </AppContextProvider>
    )
}

I debug the method setIsDrawerOpen and I found a glitch, the default object in AppContext wasn't replace by the new object in value attribute of AppContext.Provider.
If I pass an empty object as default value for AppContext has the same result, it's never rewrite by the value.
Could you see if I missing something in the definition of the context?
Thanks in advance!

could u try using the callback provided in usestates for your toggleDrawer like so ? setIsDrawerOpen((prev) => !prev), change the context file accordingly too

I try it before and doesn't work, also it throws an error of type : Argument of type '(previous: any) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'.

You can only use context from children component wrapped into context provider. What you are trying to do here is to use context in the same component that wrap children with context provider:
const GlobalLayout: React.FC<GlobalLayoutProps> = props => {
    const { isDrawerOpen, setIsDrawerOpen } = useAppContext();
    const [drawerWidth, setDrawerWidth] = useState<string>('68px');

    const toggleDrawer = () => {
        setIsDrawerOpen(!isDrawerOpen);
    };
    //This useEffect never triggers because isDrawerOpen never changes
    useEffect(() => {
        if (isDrawerOpen) {
            setDrawerWidth('240px');
        } else {
            setDrawerWidth('68px');
        }
    }, [isDrawerOpen]);

    return (
     <AppContextProvider>
       <Button onClick={toggleDrawer}>Test</Button>.
     </AppContextProvider>
    )
}

Correct version:

const DrawerToggle: React.FC = () => {
    const { isDrawerOpen, setIsDrawerOpen } = useAppContext();
    const [drawerWidth, setDrawerWidth] = useState<string>('68px');

    const toggleDrawer = () => {
        setIsDrawerOpen(!isDrawerOpen);
    };
    //This useEffect never triggers because isDrawerOpen never changes
    useEffect(() => {
        if (isDrawerOpen) {
            setDrawerWidth('240px');
        } else {
            setDrawerWidth('68px');
        }
    }, [isDrawerOpen]);

    return (
       <Button onClick={toggleDrawer}>Test</Button>.
    )
}

const GlobalLayout: React.FC<GlobalLayoutProps> = props => {
    return (
     <AppContextProvider>
       <DrawerToggle  />.
     </AppContextProvider>
    )
}



Following your instructions, I add ContextLayout component which uses AppContextProvider and accept children, and wrap GlobalLayout content with ContextLayout and still have the same issue

please take a look of the project https://gitlab.com/iximware/patasalada
